# Find closest Store SQL

Tags: sql

[Output of what I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDU6D.png)

This is what I'd like to get to:

I have a Table which holds my store locations and their long and lat in three columns, and another table which holds my customer key their long and lat. in my output id like to see a column with closest store and a column with distance to the closest store.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the guidelines on how to ask questions and edit or create a new post based on this information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should post this as an answer and then accept your own answer. Congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, I found how to do it:

1) DECLARE @start_location GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(Lat,Long,4326)

2) SELECT ID, @start_location.STDistance(Location)/1609.344 [YourTableName] from (SELECT ID, GEOGRAPHY::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326) as Location FROM [TheTableWhereYourZipInfoIsStored]

notes: /1609.344 is because you want to convert to miles from meters.